# Why do I have to configure z-index to be 9999

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying an image on top of another and need to use :

```
z-index: 9999
```

I would have though that `z-index: 999` would be enough as there are not 998 elements overlay-ed over each other. I'm not pasting more code as its not mine and private.

Why would I need to set a z-index so high even when there are just approx 5 images overlay ed over each other currently ?

Comment: It's not the amount of elements, it's the z-index number, if another element has a z-index of 9998, you need to have a higher number to appear on top (plus some extra rules and shiz I think.. lol =/)

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually doesn't matter if the `z-index` is exactly 9999, it just needs to be higher than any other defined z-indices, so picking a high number like 9999 is safer that way.

Answer (score 1):

Often z-index is given arbitrary "high enough" number to be reasonably sure element would be *really* on top. It doesn't have to be this high, 9999 just makes sure if there is by a chance element with z-index 9998, 3000, 100 ...etc. (anything below 9999) - it will be above it.